# QuickActions like the Twitter app

Tags: android

I want to add ***Pattern 6: QuickActions*** from [android's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html) to my app.

Any code snippet?

Anyone try to do it already?

Should this work on android 1.5?

Comment: I would also be very interested into a snippet.

Comment: +1 A snippet will help me greatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That app is going to be open sourced at some point so you may want to wait until then.  But it could be done with a `Dialog` with a custom background drawable, and using `Window.LayoutParams` to position the dialog.

Answer (score 13):

I just found this question right after I posted my own question/answer. Here's the code I developed for this. http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/

Answer (score 6):

I also have been searching for this and found someone through the wave of the Google IO session who has implemented such thing.

He posted the [code](http://github.com/ruqqq/WorldHeritageSite/blob/master/src/sg/ruqqq/WHSFinder/QuickActionWindow.java) on GitHub. I just tested it, and it works just great!

You'll also need some ressources from the project (drawables, styles..).

Comment: I am trying to utilize some of the code from the link that you posted above within my application and am finding it difficult to understand how to do this.  Any ideas how to implement the QuickActionWindow and QuickActionItem with other code?

Comment: Take a look at 
http://github.com/ruqqq/WorldHeritageSite/blob/master/src/sg/ruqqq/WHSFinder/WHSListActivity.java
Lines 123-204.
It is really easy to use...

Answer (score 5):

Look at line 1310 of [ContactsListActivity.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java;h=24c7100e91d16d38da94914407360d49fadb27f9;hb=HEAD) from the Contacts application.  It's the code that creates the intent for the contact shortcuts on the home screen that launch the quick actions intent for a contact.

This won't work before eclair.

Answer (score 5):

Until the official Twitter app is open sourced by Google, you may want to take a look at [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) implementation:

It's really easy to use and works great.