# Android popup menu

Tags: android, menu, popup, contacts

I am making an Android app.  I have a list of items displaying.  I am looking to create a popup menu just like the one that pops up when you tap the avatar of a contact in the contact list.  I have tried looking through the Android reference but can not find it.

Has anyone created one of these popup menus? A link to the reference or a code sample is fine.

Screenshot of menu:

http://www.youchoob.org/pics/popup.jpg

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: I found a screenshot of the menu http://youchoob.org/popup.jpg

Comment: Nice find fedj. I didn't know if there was any code floating out there for the 'Quick Action'. Hopefully Android makes this part of the API soon.

Comment: Yep but the problem stays for older versions of android. The problem is that HTC, Samsung and others are "a bit" slow to make updates. That's why we (android developers) always need to find tricks :s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are describing is called a 'Quick Action'. This is actually a user interface pattern - there isn't an existing widget or anything in the API for this. They discussed it at Google IO (See in this [video here](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html), at the 15:40 mark), and also there has been some discussion on how to implement it on stack overflow, specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern) question. If you start digging around (now that you know the name of what you are looking for) you might find more.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the contacts is open source.  You should look around here and see if you can find it.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts

I'm looking now if I find it I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

you can find "QuickAction" widget in

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

below is a demo activity

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/QuickActionActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code OR framework from here :

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/