# Searchbar just like twitter app in android

Tags: android, user-interface, twitter, searchbar

I wounder if there some example on how to create a searchbar just like twitter app in android?
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/S-rmYdiUTCI/AAAAAAAAAEE/hIO9GD53SLc/s1600/search2.png

and also I wonder about the popup.

Are there any samples?

Comment: You may want to check this question's answer on the issue of a Twitter-like popup ,http://stackoverflow.com/a/31457200/1464571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the search bar, I would just implement a custom Activity that handles the search action within your app.  If you notice, when you press search from within Twitter it takes you to an entire new screen, with that bar at the top, a location bar below that, and then a ListView of suggestions.  That just looks like a custom Activity to me that mimics the built in search function.  I could be wrong, but I know of no way to customize the built in search bar that heavily.

As for the popup, look at the answers to this question: [Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)