# Custom ActionBar Overflow Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make an ActionBar Menu OverFlow. The type twitter does. Where The Name and The UserName shows on the first Item on the OverFlow. So, I did this, but it's not taking any effect, any help would be appreciated. There is my code:

**MyActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.username);
    View usname = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_menu_overflow, null);
    TextView uName = (TextView) usname.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
    TextView slug = (TextView) usname.findViewById(R.id.slugName);
    uName.setText("Users");
    slug.setText("Tracer");
    menuItem.setActionView(usname);
    //MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItem, usname);

    //menuItem.setTitle("Users");
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:title="@string/username"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**action_menu_overflow.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/slugLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/profileName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/slugName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Twitter Menu OverFlow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved by use of PopUpMenu,  which the normal android overflow menu uses since it is constrained to not easily be used with complex custom layout/adapter . However, this twitter-like overflow menu can easily be achieved by use of ListPopupWindow, which is made to be easily used with more complex layouts/adapters.

To make this simple ,you can have a function in your activity/fragment to setup the ListPopupWindow . This is an example:

```
public void onListPopUp(View anchor)
    {
        // This a sample dat to fill our ListView
        ArrayList<Person> personItem = new ArrayList<Person>();
        personItem.add(new Person(R.drawable.remove_placeholder_userpic, "Mamluki", "@DigitalSurgeonR"));
        personItem.add(new Person(0, "Lists", "@Lists"));
        personItem.add(new Person(0, "Drafts", "@Drafts"));
        personItem.add(new Person(0, "Accounts", "@Accounts"));
        // Initialise our adapter
        ListPopupWindowAdapter mListPopUpAdapter = new ListPopupWindowAdapter(this, personItem);

        //Initialise our ListPopupWindow instance
        final ListPopupWindow pop = new ListPopupWindow(this);
        // Configure ListPopupWindow properties
        pop.setAdapter(mListPopUpAdapter);
        // Set the view below/above which ListPopupWindow dropdowns
        pop.setAnchorView(anchor);
        // Setting this enables window to be dismissed by click outside ListPopupWindow
        pop.setModal(true);
        // Sets the width of the ListPopupWindow
        pop.setContentWidth(150);
        // Sets the Height of the ListPopupWindow
        pop.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Set up a click listener for the ListView items
        pop.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Dismiss the LisPopupWindow when a list item is clicked
                pop.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked ListPopUp item " + ((Person) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        pop.show();
    }
```

This function can be called from the method override below -:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_overflow:
                // Works as long as list item is always visible and does not go into the menu overflow
                final View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_overflow);
                onListPopUp(menuItemView);
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "You called me OverFlow");

                return true;
            default:
            {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Our adapter will extend the BaseAdapter and will have the following code snippet .

```
public class ListPopupWindowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Variables
    // ----------------------------------------
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Person> personItem;
    // ----------------------------------------
    // Methods
    // ----------------------------------------

    public ListPopupWindowAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> personItem)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.personItem = personItem;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView profilePic;
        TextView name;
        TextView userName;
        boolean isWithPicture = (personItem.get(position).getProfilePic() != 0);

            // Small List View , no need to recycle views
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // Is this the row with the p.picture
            if(isWithPicture)
            {
                //Layout for the top row with profile picture /Avatar
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_overflow_item_row, parent, false);

                profilePic = (ImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.imageProfilePic);
                profilePic.setImageResource(personItem.get(position).getProfilePic());

                userName = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
                userName.setText(personItem.get(position).getUserName());
            }
            else
            {
                //Layout for the other layout without an images
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_overflow_item_row_text, parent, false);
            }


        name = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        name.setText(personItem.get(position).getName());


        return convertView ;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------
    //  Implemented
    // ----------------------------------------
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index)
    {
        return personItem.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return personItem.size();
    }

}
```

We have two layouts . One for the listView top row item and another for the other rows.

*toolbar_overfow_row_item.xml* -top row item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@color/apptheme_accent_teal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mamluki"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"

            android:text="\@DigitalSurgeonR"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

*toolbar_overfow_row_item_text.xml* -other row items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="14dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mamluki"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Additionally , to set the position of the [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)

we can use methods:-

```
 setVerticalOffset(int offset)
 setHorizontalOffset(int offset)
```

The Horizontal & Vertical offset are 0 by default . Setting the vertical offset to *setVerticalOffset(-36)* makes the *ListPopupWindow* overlay the actionbar/toolbar . The more negative value pushes it further up . Alternatively you can set it as a Style in your *styles.xml* like below

```
    <style name="AppThemeToolBar" parent="AppBaseThemeNoActionBar.Dark" >
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- ListPopUpWindow styles -->
            <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.App.ListPopupWindow</item>
        </style>

<!-- Widget styles -->
    <style name="Widget" />

    <style name="Widget.App" parent="Widget" />
    <!-- Widget ListPopUpWindow Style-->
        <style name="Widget.App.ListPopupWindow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow">
            <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-36px</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are setting an actionView to the menu item but this item will never be shown as action : `app:showAsAction="never"` so unfortunately you can't go that way (if you set this to `ifRoom` you will have your custom layout displayed in the action bar).

To display profile name you can use [setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)) but you will not have your custom layout.

I haven't find yet how to customize ActionBar dropdown menu items without creating a custom view for the ActionBar and a [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) for the dropdown menu...

Comment: Please check this image, the first Item on the List is what I'm trying to do, that wouldn't solve it. It'll only show the view on the Actionbar [ItemViewImage](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikdrsfa0tqjaice/Screenshot_2014-11-06-11-26-15.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Otieno Rowland answer above, I was able to achieve this in Kotlin.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxeIV.png)
MainActivity class

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        bottomNavigationView.background = null
        bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false
        toolbar.title = "Home"
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.downloadresized_modified)
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_menu)
        toolbar.logoDescription = "Company Logo"
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { p0 ->
            val menuItemView = findViewById<View>(R.id.notifications)
            when (p0!!.itemId) {
                R.id.about_us -> Toast.makeText(this, "About Us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.shop -> Toast.makeText(this, p0.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.notifications -> Toast.makeText(this, p0.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.app_bar_search -> Toast.makeText(this, p0.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.profile -> onListPopup(menuItemView)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun onListPopup(anchor: View){
        val menuItems: ArrayList<Menu> = ArrayList()
        menuItems.add(Menu(R.drawable.logo_2, "Mohammed Trouble", "Mdee@gmail.com"))
        menuItems.add( Menu(0, "About Us", "@About_Us"))
        menuItems.add( Menu(0, "Contact Us", "@Contact_Us"))
        menuItems.add( Menu(0, "Settings", "@Settings"))
        menuItems.add( Menu(0, "DONATE", "@Donate"))

        val listPopupAdapter = ListPopupWindowAdapter(this,menuItems)
        val pop = ListPopupWindow(this)
        pop.setAdapter(listPopupAdapter)
        pop.anchorView = anchor
        pop.isModal = true
        pop.width = ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT
        pop.setContentWidth(450)
        pop.horizontalOffset = -5
        pop.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, l -> // Dismiss the LisPopupWindow when a list item is clicked
            pop.dismiss()
            Log.w("MainActivityTAG","Item clicked")
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "Clicked ListPopUp item " + (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position) as Menu).name,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
        pop.show()
    }
```

ListPopupWindowAdapter class

```
class ListPopupWindowAdapter(private val context: Context, private val menuItems:ArrayList<Menu>): BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return menuItems.size
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return menuItems[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

     override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val convertView: View
        val profilePic: ImageView?
         val userName:TextView?
        val isWithPicture: Boolean = menuItems[p0].getProfilePic()!= 0
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        if(isWithPicture){
            convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_overflow_top_row,p2,false)
            profilePic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfilePic)
            profilePic.setImageResource(menuItems[p0].getProfilePic())

            userName =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.textUsername)
            userName.text = (menuItems[p0].getUserName())
        }else{
            convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_overflow_bottom_row,p2,false)
        }
         val name: TextView? = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)
         name!!.text = (menuItems[p0].getName())
         return convertView
    }
```

Menu class

```
data class Menu(val profilePic: Int, val name:String, val userName:String){
    @JvmName("getProfilePic1")
    fun getProfilePic(): Int {
        return profilePic
    }

    @JvmName("getUserName1")
    fun getUserName(): String {
        return userName
    }

    fun getName(): CharSequence {
        return name
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_chat_24"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<!--    <include-->
<!--        layout="@layout/activity_content_page"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar_overflow_bottom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/_1609"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="14dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/_1609"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Mamluki"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:drawableBottomCompat="@color/purple_200" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar_overflow_top_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mohammed Trouble"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:text="\@DigitalSurgeonR"

            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:title="@string/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Wizkid"
        android:icon="@drawable/_1_star_boy_modified"
        android:title="@string/wizkid" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        android:title="@string/shop" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Projects"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_event_note_24"
        android:title="@string/projects" />

</menu>
```

toolbar_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        android:title="@string/shop"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications_24"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```