# How to replicate the popup box in the Twitter Android app?

Tags: android, listview, twitter

The Official Twitter Android app has a neat way of presenting a message bubble when you click on a button. I was wondering how that can be done using the Android SDK?

Comment: I don't use the official Android Twitter app so I'm not sure what you mean, but it might be this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Quick Actions? You should find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)