# How can I create a slide out options menu for Android ListView items?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making an Android app and one of the activities in the app is a List Activity. I want the ListView to have the slide out options menu for the list items like you often see in apps like twitter:

[image: Twitter Slide Out Options Menu]

I thought I read a while back that Android had a feature like this included in the sdk, but I can't seem to find any documentation or tutorials on it. Part of my problem is that I don't know exactly what the feature is called. I have done quite a bit of searching, but I haven't come up with anything useful. I am hoping that someone with a bit of Android development experience has seen this before and could recommend a resource or two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899036/how-to-replicate-the-popup-box-in-the-twitter-android-app). They're called [quick actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern).