# Twitter UI control

Tags: android

Who knows what is this widget Twitter application uses? How to create one?

[image]

Comment: I don’t have an answer, but grepping for “QuickContact” and “QUICK_CONTACT” in [platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary) may help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)

Comment: @siik Hi Can u please tell me how to tweet using api how can i make a simple app that can tweet please rply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This UI is known as [Quick Contact Badge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html)

See this link if you want to create your own :

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Looks like this is just an easy way to use contact's details. Is it possible to configure this widget for my own purposes?