# Android - What is that popup called when you click a contact's icon?

Tags: android, view, png

On stock android, what is that thing called when you click a contact's picture and it brings up a list of quick links?  this is also what you see when you long hold a icon in ADW Launcher.

More importantly though, i would like to know which png files in the folder `frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi` (from cm7 source, aka framework-res.apk) relate to that android view? (That is assuming they are in that folder, if not let me know).

I want to edit these but i cant for the life of me figure out which files relate to it. I have been searching around for a while and cant find anything on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as [`Quick Contact Badge`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html)

See Here:

[Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)