# Custom quick action on a widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to develop a custom quick action window to be shown on clicking on the widget.
Something similar to what is there in Twitter application ([Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)). Am facing problems in adding custom quick action view due to limitations of the remote views used in widgets.

Could any one please help me on this??

Thanks,
Kabini

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/

It's a short, easily-digested demo of a possible approach for implementing something similar to Quick Actions.