# Android "Share" Submenu

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)

how can we make submenu like android

Answer (score 1):

see the below link.It may be useful for u [Sub Menu](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/08/android-development-submenus/)

Comment: Thanks @User333 but i don't want dialog view.. i want same as display above.

Comment: For this u write the code for sending mail when u click on the share button.Then automatically number of posibilities are displayed like above .It is not a  sub menu

Comment: yaa true, but here i am talking about it's view. when we choose default menu option of android it shows the components in dialog box http://www.barebonescoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/submenuShowing.png. I want view same as above display..