# Different OnClick actions for subviews in ListView item and fancy context menu bubble

Tags: android, listview, onclick, contextmenu

I'm writing an app and I have a ListView, which items are ImageView and TextView.
I'd like to determine whether user have clicked the icon or the text to handle diferrent actions for each case. I want to achieve similar effect like in stock contacts app.

First question: How to achieve the effect wich I've mentioned above?

Second question: In the stock contacts app when we click on a photo, a fancy bubble with some actions inside appears. How is it called? Where to get it from?

Thanks.

(edit)
ok, i've found something according to my second question:
[How to make a fancy transparent menu like the "share menu" in Android gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997166/how-to-make-a-fancy-transparent-menu-like-the-share-menu-in-android-gallery)

Comment: can you submit the second part as a separate question, please ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer on your first question: you should attach `onClickListeners` to each of your row's views in your Adapter's `getView()` method. This should do it.

Comment: Oh, it was obvious, thank you. Stupid me:) Waiting for reply on second question.

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful =)