# Android: PopUp window with callout

Tags: android

I am trying to display a callout. I have a button in my main layout. Onclick of this `Button` I need to show a window popup with an arrow poiting to the button clicked. I tried using `PopupWindow`, but this shows a normal popup, I need to show it like a callout, coming out from the button. Any suggestions?

This is my coe so far

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View mView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lt_popupwindow,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ltPopUpParent));              
            View mView2= inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ltMainParent));
            PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,false);
            mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mView2, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look here If you have not before , This might help you.

[Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)

Comment: Thanks sat, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PopupWindow-style liked widget might help you.

[PointerPopupWindow](https://github.com/pinguo-marui/PointerPopupWindow)