# Android slider / drawer similar to gtalk app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a drawer / panel similar to the one in gtalk below. On click of the Image in the List Item inside gTalk a drawer opens up with these options and i want to have something similar for my app which has ListView.

What is this panel called as? Is this a SlideDrawer or something else? Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called [QuickActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern). Here's a [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).