# Horizontal icons List dialog in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create an horizontal icons selection dialog like the one in the below picture?
I saw this in many applications but couldn't find an how-to guide...

[image: Horizontal list]

Thanks...

Comment: While this pattern is still in use by a number of Android 2.x apps it has more or less fallen out of fashion in Android 3 and 4, replaced by `PopupMenu` and `ActionMode`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html The system Quick Contacts now has a different character as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the QuickAction ui pattern. For more information check here: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ and here: [Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)

Hope this helps!