# What is this controlled called?

Tags: android

I wan't to use this controll in my app but cant find which it is.

Im looking for the "slide out options"-panel thing marked in red:

[image]

Comment: QuickAction just use search on SO to get implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referred to as a QuickAction, and while it's not directly available as a widget in the SDK (it's actually built out of `PopupWindow`) you can find a [tutorial with available sample code here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).

HTH

Answer (score 2):

it's called quick action, android has no by default, but it is already implemented in greed droid 
https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Cheers

PS you can read question about this control btw [Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern) it has a lot of information