# Android menu/dialog appear above selected list Item

Tags: android, listview

There is this one Android app called Out of Milk that has a menu appear above a selected item in a list view, I was wondering how would I do that for my list view?

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called quick action. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern/3619450#3619450) link to see how it is done.