# Android : Get view Reference to a Menu Item

Tags: android, view, menu, menuitem, quickaction

I plan to use quick actions UI pattern in my application. [Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern) . The quick action window needs a pivot view to stick to.

```
    quickAction.show(View pivotView);
```

I intend to use quick action for the menu Item, I can get access to the item that is clicked. 
But the problem is i need to reference a view from the menu item so that i can pass it to the quick action.

How can i get reference to a view in the menuItem that is selected.

Comment: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ have you used this link..

Comment: @NikhilreddyGujjula link is not working.

Comment: long back i have tried it has worked for me but i am not having code for me sry..

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can achieve this by providing your menu item with an actionViewClass property in xml and then you will be able to get the pivot view u wanted. The code would be something like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_find"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
    />
```

In your OnCreateOptionsMenu do this

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    locButton = (ImageButton) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_find).getActionView();
    locButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            createPopup();
            mQuickAction.show(v);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a weird problem where viewfinder would find a spiner in actionbar when on android 4.1 but on 4.2 it just returned null,this fixed it.

Comment: setOnMenuItemClickListener will be helpful for me, in case you want to perform direct operation with Menu Item

Comment: use app:actionViewClass if you use recent library.  (res-auto)

Answer (score 46):

Old question, but I ran into some issues with the `actionViewClass` attribute. For anyone who runs into this later...

Calling `findViewById(R.id.mnu_item)` in `onOptionsItemSelected` will return a `View` anchor.

`QuickActions` on the `MenuItems` aren't good design, but I found that they are the simplest way to implement submenus with custom backgrounds.

Comment: I guess you will need to click the 'menuItem' at least once before you could get the 'menuItem' 'view' anchor.

Comment: Right, the `findViewById()` call would have to be done at run time

Comment: Thanks @ASH answer failed if we put actionViewClass. This is working great.

Answer (score 27):

Inorder to **get reference Views of menu items** we need to do this,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.section, menu);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_preview);
            // SOME OF YOUR TASK AFTER GETTING VIEW REFERENCE

        }
    });


    return true;
}
```

Comment: the best way, without creating any custom view and setactionview

Comment: It's so ugly (thanks api) but this is really work solution, thanks a lot

Comment: Doesn't work in api 28

Comment: You are amazing, this worked for me. Thanks so much for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

*An update for anyone that want to find the menu view item for other reasons (like I wanted).*

If you have access to and use AppCompat's Toolbar there is a way. It's not the most efficient way, but it's the easiest way I've found to access the menu item's view.

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // Find Menu
    for (int toolbarChildIndex = 0; toolbarChildIndex < toolbar.getChildCount(); toolbarChildIndex++) {
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(toolbarChildIndex);

        // Found Menu
        if (view instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            ActionMenuView menuView = (ActionMenuView) view;

            // All menu items
            for (int menuChildIndex = 0; menuChildIndex < menuView.getChildCount(); menuChildIndex++) {
                ActionMenuItemView itemView = (ActionMenuItemView) menuView.getChildAt(menuChildIndex);
                // Do something to itemView...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Universal code which also works on Android 10

```
/**
* pass toolbar and menu item id, i.e. R.id.menu_refresh
*/
@Nullable
@Throws(
    IllegalAccessException::class,
    NoSuchFieldException::class
)
fun getMenuItemView(toolbar: Toolbar?, @IdRes menuItemId: Int): View? {
    val mMenuView: Field = Toolbar::class.java.getDeclaredField("mMenuView")
    mMenuView.setAccessible(true)
    val menuView: Any? = mMenuView.get(toolbar)
    (menuView as ViewGroup).children.forEach {
        if(it.id == menuItemId) {
            return it
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Soon this will be blocked on the getDeclaredField had to add this  @SuppressLint("SoonBlockedPrivateApi")

Answer (score -2):

in the main activity class, best to override the onOptionsItemSelected(...) method; should be something as below:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // the id is of type int
  int someId = item.getItemId();
  // can use an if() or switch() statement to check if id is selected
  //a Toast message can be used to show item is selected
}
```