# Menu View creation in lifecycle

Tags: android, android-menu

I need to get a reference to a `MenuItem`'s corresponding `View` without [specifying a custom one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(int)). Using `findViewById()` with a menu item's ID returns null when called from `Activity#onCreate()` or `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. However, as a few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344616/get-the-view-from-the-action-bar-menu-item#answer-18427508) to other questions point out, `findViewById()` *does* return the view when called from `onOptionsItemSelected()` or from a runnable posted in `Activity#onCreate()`, like so...

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        findViewById(R.id.some_view);
    }
});
```

So it seems that at some point, Android takes the `Menu` that you populate in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and creates the corresponding `View`s that are shown on screen. A `Runnable` posted from `onCreate()` *happens* to get run after that happens. But it feels so hacky to assume that will always be the case instead of actually listening for some kind of `menuViewsCreated()` event.

So that brings me to my question – *does* Android provide an event that tells developers that the menu `View`s have been created?

Answer (score 0):

It's late but it may help some one else 
you must use `new Handler()` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.section, menu);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
            //TODO

        }
    });


    return true;
}
```