# Animating in TableRows in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a nav drawer which contains a `TableLayout` with a few `TableRows`, each simply containing a `TextView`. Upon the drawer opening, Id like to do a very small sliding in animation of the TableRows/TextViews, where they each slide in a tad later than the previous, very similar to the drawer found in the Sprig app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eatsprig&hl=en

I know that usually for a simple animation I would create a xml file in /res/anim/ and then load the animation with `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.myanim)` and then start the animation with the `.startAnimation()` method, but im not sure how to go about doing an animation as described above. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'd add a `AnimationListener` for each `Animation` and start the next `Animation` `onAnimationEnd`. You can test it with the default `android.R.anim.slide_in_right` `Animation`

Comment: Well with 5+ items thats quite a few nested callbacks, surely theres another way? Also, is there a way to set the animation via xml? I see android:layoutAnimation but im assuming that would only be called on initial layout, not everytime the drawer opens.

Comment: Yep, but you could use the same `Animation` again. (Maintaining your `Views` in an `Array`, counting which... etc.) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27563468/4908802) is not what you want, but maybe it can inspire you. You could start each `Animation` on a specific offset.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.