# How To Get Action View Of Menu Item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

This is My Code

**home.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_shopping_cart"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_cart_button"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Shopping Cart" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifications_button"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Notifications" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="OverFlow">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_my_account"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="My Account" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_current_orders"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="My Orders" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_wish_list"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="My Wishlist" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_contact_us"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Contact Us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_logout"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I want the View **"menu_overflow"** how can I get that?

I tried Following way :

**Activity.java** code

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
      final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_overflow);
      View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow);
      new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                        .setTarget(mOverFlowIcon)
                        .setRadius(10)
                        .setMaskColour(Color.argb(150, 0, 0, 0))
                        .setContentText("Find Your Wishlist Here") // optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
                        .setDismissOnTouch(true)
                        .show();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But is returning view is **null**.

Please help...thanx

Comment: @Harshad Please Check the Activity Code

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533513/4685284

Answer (score 13):

Are you inflating the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu? It appears that when onCreateOptionsMenu is executed, the xml inflation is added to the event queue, rather than inflating immediately. This is what causes your null pointer when you execute findViewById(). Try putting your view lookup inside a Handler. The code within the Handler is added to the message queue and will therefore be executed after the menu is inflated. This will resolve your null pointer. It will look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow);
            new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                    .setTarget(view)
                    .setRadius(10)
                    .setMaskColour(Color.argb(150, 0, 0, 0))
                    .setContentText("Find Your Wishlist Here") // optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
                    .setDismissOnTouch(true)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get a reference to the `MenuItem` by overriding the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem actionViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

If you want a reference to the `ActionView` you can do this with the method `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(MenuItem)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem actionViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    View v = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(actionViewItem);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: `MenuItemCompat.getActionView` is deprecated. `MenuItem.getActionView` should be used instead.

Comment: @fdermishin you mean `View v =  actionViewItem.getActionView();` don't you? x

Comment: In some occasions while the menu item is already there, the action view turns out to be still null, as it seems to first add the menu, then inflate the UI. Any tricks on how to wait for the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:title="OverFlow"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton">
```

Note this lines:

```
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_shopping_cart:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_shopping_cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_notifications:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_overflow:
                Toast.makeText(this, "menu_overflow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_my_account:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_my_account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_current_orders:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_current_orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_wish_list:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_wish_list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_contact_us:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_contact_us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;



        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Take care of the name of your xml (that is home.xml)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I want the menu_overflow view on onOptionsCreate. I am showcasing tutorial for overflow icon, thats why I want view of over Flow menu..Do you know how to get that?