# Get view from MenuItem which property "showAsAction" never

Tags: android, menu-items

I use this [library](https://github.com/wooplr/Spotlight) to show a Guide Tour. I want to implement the Spotlight into `Menu Item` which have property `showAsAction` as never. Below my snippet code :

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menu_item_refresh);
        new SpotlightView.Builder(getActivity())
                .introAnimationDuration(400)
                .enableRevealAnimation(true)
                .performClick(true)
                .fadeinTextDuration(400)
                .headingTvColor(Color.parseColor("#eb273f"))
                .headingTvSize(32)
                .headingTvText("")
                .subHeadingTvColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                .subHeadingTvSize(16)
                .subHeadingTvText("Tap on chart to show detail")
                .maskColor(Color.parseColor("#dc000000"))
                .target(view)
                .lineAnimDuration(400)
                .lineAndArcColor(Color.parseColor("#eb273f"))
                .dismissOnTouch(true)
                .dismissOnBackPress(true)
                .enableDismissAfterShown(true)
                .usageId("")
                .show();
```

I get this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: x.com.d, PID: 15058
                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getLocationInWindow(int[])' on a null object reference
                 at com.wooplr.spotlight.target.ViewTarget.getPoint(ViewTarget.java:23)
                 at com.wooplr.spotlight.shape.Circle.getFocusPoint(Circle.java:36)
                 at com.wooplr.spotlight.shape.Circle.<init>(Circle.java:24)
                 at com.wooplr.spotlight.SpotlightView$Builder.build(SpotlightView.java:1082)
                 at com.wooplr.spotlight.SpotlightView$Builder.show(SpotlightView.java:1091)
```

I see the error happened because the `Menu Item` is invisible on the main view. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301667/how-to-get-action-view-of-menu-item/33337827#33337827) related question but I still get same error. Is possible to get that item which is invisible (never as action)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42955702/7319247) . JarredRummler answer get the `OverflowbMenuButton` as a `ImageView`. Use that method and cast the `OverflowMenuButton` as View and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `override` the following `method` to access the `MenuItem View`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.the_one_to_spotlight);
    View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);

   // Now do whatever you want with the View

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I assume `.target(view)` will do the trick in this case.

If that still does not give you the `View` you need, I would consider changing your `showAsAction`. Read more useful information about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23080138/5457878

Comment: Your code still have same error, but that is usefull link thank you. Its mean the "hidden" menu item can't be cast into a view?

Comment: If the view is `GONE` you can't get it. If it's `INVISIBLE` then you should be able to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756190/5457878