# invalidateOptionMenu() disables the clicking functionality of toolbar menu

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

In my eCommerce app, I am using cart basket with count textview. Here for updates the cart count textview I used `invalidateOptionMenu();` after that the clicking of cart navigates next fragment is not working. Even I tried in many ways,but did not worked.Please help me

This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


        badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();           /*-------Cart Basket with Counter---------*/
        basketCount = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        CommonUtil.dbUtil.open();
        try {
            MainActivity.basketCount.setText(String.valueOf(CommonUtil.dbUtil.getCartItem().getCount()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.basketCount.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
        }

        badgeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Cart Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*
                * menuItemClicked represents ToolBar OverFlow (...) menu is clicked.
                * */
                Config.menuItemClicked = true;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("cart_Clicked", Config.menuItemClicked);
                editor.apply();

                Intent next = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(next);

            }
        });

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling `invalidateOptionMenu()` inside your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` you should call it when you are updating the `count value` that you set in `basketCount` `TextView`.

Calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` is of no avail there, so when you add item to your cart at that you should call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: @ParamaSudha did this help or any issues you faced ?

Comment: i added after updating my textview, but its not wokring