# Android change menu item Text color dynamically

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am trying to change menu item text color dynamically.

I have a solution that works for menu icons, it uses the color filter as follows:

```
Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();

        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(new
                    PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        }
        menuItem.setIcon(drawable);
```

Output:[image]

I am unable to change the color of menu item text. To make this work I used the following code:

```
 SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), 0, s.length(), 0);
                menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

Output:[image]

the color of "SAVE" is what I am trying to change.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

add this theme in style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">    
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_color</item>    
</style>
```

and apply the theme to toolbar

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify text color from java code instead of specifying it in XML?
e.g I am specifying  actionMenuTextColor = white in style/XML & want to change it to RED in activity at runtime. How to do that?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614293/android-get-view-reference-to-a-menu-item   hope it will help you.

Comment: He wants to do it dynamically not the whole theme file!

Answer (score 1):

add menu style

```
<style name="optionMenuTextApearance" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

called it in menu

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/optionMenuTextApearance</item>
```

Runtime change menu color

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    styleMenuButton();
    return result;
}

private void styleMenuButton() {
    // Find the menu item you want to style
    View view = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM_ID_HERE);

    // Cast to a TextView instance if the menu item was found
    if (view != null && view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) view).setTextColor( Color.BLUE ); // Make text colour blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify text color from java code instead of specifying it in XML?
e.g I am specifying  actionMenuTextColor = white in style/XML & want to change it to RED in activity at runtime. How to do that?

Comment: I want to change the color of that "save" menu item in activity as shown below:

    `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_done, menu);

        MenuItem saveMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_done);
        // I want to change saveMenuItem text
        
        
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }`

Comment: View view = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM_ID_HERE);
always returns null.

Comment: You have to find the Appear view, this finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your SpannableString on your Menu Item.
Add the following line after you build a SpannableString:

```
menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

Since your `menuItem.getTitle()` is only providing a String value for making a SpannableString, not the reference as a menu item title.

Comment: I have to change menu item text color not action bar title color.

Comment: @PrashantKawtikwar Sorry I was confused, try the edited answer.

Comment: Did you put your code in `onCreateOptionsMenu`? You should override that method in order to change the menu.

Comment: Yes. I wrote the code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

Comment: That sounds weird. How does your xml layout look like?