# registerForContextMenu throws null pointer exception when menu_item is passed a a view

Tags: android, contextmenu

When I click a menu item, I want to generate a `context menu` with options for the user to select.
But its throwing `null pointer exception`.

#  menu_main.xml #

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.bremachitra.mynotepad.MainActivity">
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_view"
        android:title="View"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton" />
</menu>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
    if(id == R.id.action_view)
     { 
        ImageButton viewButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.action_view);
         registerForContextMenu(viewButton);
            }

     @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            Toast.makeText(this,"context",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view,menu);
        }



      @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_grid:
                Toast.makeText(this,"grid view",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
                case R.id.action_list:
                Toast.makeText(this,"List view",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is for imageview.
You cannot directly access a menu source.
You should use inflater(or menuInflater) or Menu object:

viewButton = (ImageButton) menu.findViewById(R.id.action_view);

[This link is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614293/android-get-view-reference-to-a-menu-item)

put imageview in onCreateOptonsMenu() method and use menu parameter for findViewById:

viewButton = (ImageButton) menu.findViewById(R.id.action_view);

Comment: Hi I have already inflated the file  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

Comment: put imageview in onCreateOptonsMenu() method and use 
menu for findviewById :

viewButton = (ImageButton) menu.findViewById(R.id.action_view);