# Android Share Menu in Gallery app

Tags: android

I want to menu like android default gallery app share option.how do this menu in android sdk any one help with any code or tutorial with greatly appreciated!

I want output Like below Screen Shot:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nothing but the Quick Action bar Demo you are looking for. 
Here are few examples which will get you started with,

first link is from StackOverflow which has discussed about it,

[Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3059155/603744)

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: well, how abt accepting it as the answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: stack overflow shows You can accept an answer in 3 minutes,i am accept after 3 minutes!