# What is the name of this control in android

Tags: android

May i know the name of the below placed image control, also please tell me how to implement similar control in my application.

This control appears, after long press on contact image.

[image]

Comment: That's an HTC device - correct? Technically speaking it's a Context Menu but it's specific to the HTC Sense UI and the library isn't publically accessible for devs to use. You could do a search on 'custom context menu' or a similar phrase.

Comment: Its Sony Ericsson phone control

Comment: Oh, OK. I stand corrected but it's very similar to what I see on my HTC Desire.

Comment: Yes, both are having similar controls, its very useful control. For developers android should provide a default control of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Quick Actions Popup, and it's not default for the framework... you have to create it yourself.

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3619450/1105376) asks about it and the answers have several links to pages telling you how to do it (there's even a couple of code repositories you could download in there).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Barak... perfect example

Answer (score 0):

That is not a built-in control, but it's not difficult to roll your own.

All you need are some nicely crafted images, the outer part can be a **LinearLayout**, which contains another **LinearLayout**, which in turn contains 3 **Buttons**, and you are done with the UI of the control.

The rest of the implementation is to calculate the coordinates to place this control.