# Is there something like a Quick Action for Holo-Themes?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-actionbar, quickaction

For my application I need something like a [Quick Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern). There are plenty of useful libraries on github since this seems not to be a feature that is officially available via the Android SDK.

But I just stumbled across something in the official gmail app:

[image]

This (the dropdown menu) is exactly what I need for my application. But I'm wondering what the the best way to achieve this functionality is. An own Quick Action implementation? Some weird Button+Spinner meet up? Are there any libraries or design guidelines that may help me on creating such a widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget used in the shown gmail application is a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) (introduced in API 11). It's behavior is documented and explained in detail [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use contextual action items (action modes). That will show action items in the action bars when you long-press an item. If you have more than fit on the action bar, they will be displayed in the overflow just as with regular action items.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html

Answer (score 0):

That's the ActionBar overflow menu. The actions in there are normal MenuItem's configured to be organized on the overflow menu if there's not enough room to display them all

Here's the [action bar documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) where you can find how to show/hide the MenuItem. Basically, you need to play around with the android:showAsAction xml attribute when defining your action bars.

```
 android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
```