# Action bar support in android support package revision 12

Tags: android, popupmenu, android-support-library

I am developing an Android application with Target SDK version 14 and minSdk version 10.
In SDK version we have support for Action Bars where as in API 10 we dont j=have support action bar.

Does android support library latest revision (android-support-v4 rev 12) has the support for Action bar and Popup menus ?

As i have written our application on API 14 and now we want to support API 10 aswell , Do we have another way to support action bars and popup menus in API 10?

Thanks, Vamsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't support ActionBar on earlier versions (before honeycomb), but there is a wonderful library you can make use of. Check out [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Even inside google guys do encourage developers to use this.

If you want to get HOLO theme for your app that is running on older versions of Android then checkout [HoloEverwhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere).

What do [you mean this by popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern) then you can do it too.

Answer (score 1):

Good news. Google has added action bar in their support library in revision 18.
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html