# how to create a popup in android?

Tags: android

i have a list.When i click on any item in the list a popup should appear where i can send messages(something like what happens when we click a user in gmail.A popup window comes up in the bottom and we can chat with that user).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to add a `Quick Action` to your application.

You should be able to get your answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957860/quickactions-like-the-twitter-app) question.