# How to open an activity in a popup window?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I have a `ListActivity` which shows list of items. I prepared another `layout` for detailed view that contains items' name, address, phone number and image. I want to show these items detailed in a popup window if one is clicked without closing my `ListActivity`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AlertDialog to do this. Look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. And scroll to Creating a Custom Dialog. Example is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: `mContext = getApplicationContext();` causes exception. Use `YourActivity.this` instead as I believe this is a reported bug

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [quickAction like the Twitter app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2957860/119895) or start a new `Activity` with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` specified in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dialogs is described on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html