# Alert Dialogue box in android

Tags: android, alert

In my code i want to close alert dialog immediately and start activities, when i select options mentioned in if- elseIf statements. I do not want ok and cancel buttons . My code work fine (statements inside if statements work but alert dialogue still there ). Thanks for help

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
    new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext());
builder.setTitle("Favourities Management");
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int selected = 0;

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @
    Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (values[which] == "Select Benificiary") {
            Intent registerUser = new Intent(FinalUtilityBillPayment.this, ListViewBeneficiaryBillPayment.class);
            FinalUtilityBillPayment.this.startActivity(registerUser);
            startActivityForResult(registerUser, 1);
        } else if (values[which] == "Add Benificiary") {
            try {
                mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ReferenceNo TEXT, Mobile Text);");

                mydb.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in creating table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            try {
                mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ReferenceNo, Mobile) VALUES('" + ref.getText().toString() + "','" + mob.getText().toString() + "')");
                mydb.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if (values[which] == "Delete Benificiary") {

            Intent registerUser = new Intent(FinalUtilityBillPayment.this, ListViewDeleteBeneficiaryBillPayment.class);
            //startActivityForResult(registerUser, 1);
            FinalUtilityBillPayment.this.startActivity(registerUser);




        }

    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();


}

});
```

Comment: If you don't want ok and cancel button than why are you using alert dialog?

Comment: dismiss is not working...i want to popup options to select on click ..is any there another option??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805906/1318946

Comment: you can use `popupWindow`. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sugestion is;

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext()); 
builder.setTitle("Favourities Management");    
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int selected = 0;
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, 
                            selected, 
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if(values[which]=="Select Benificiary"){
                                            selectBenificiary();

                                            //see more about "dialog.dismiss()" in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()
                                            dialog.dismiss();                                               
                                        } else if (values[which]=="Add Benificiary"){
                                            addBenificiary();

                                            //see more about "dialog.dismiss()" in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        } else if (values[which]=="Delete Benificiary"){
                                            deleteBenificiary();

                                            //see more about "dialog.dismiss()" in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }

                                    }
                            });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

//Add parameter case necessary
public void selectBenificiary(){
    Intent registerUser = new Intent(FinalUtilityBillPayment.this,ListViewBeneficiaryBillPayment.class);
    //  FinalUtilityBillPayment.this.startActivity(registerUser);
    startActivityForResult(registerUser, 1);
}

//Add parameter case necessary
public void addBenificiary(){
    try{
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ReferenceNo TEXT, Mobile Text);");

        mydb.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in creating table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try{
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ReferenceNo, Mobile) VALUES('"+ref.getText().toString() +"','"+  mob.getText().toString()  +"')");
        mydb.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}   

//Add parameter case necessary
public void deleteBenificiary(){
    Intent registerUser = new Intent(FinalUtilityBillPayment.this, ListViewDeleteBeneficiaryBillPayment.class);
    //startActivityForResult(registerUser, 1);
    FinalUtilityBillPayment.this.startActivity(registerUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dismiss the alert dialogue. Try this:

```
Dialogue.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... in that `onClick()` you can see the `DialogInterface dialog` that dialog name.

use this `dialog.cancel();` before calling the other activity

```
dialog.cancel();

    Intent registerUser = new Intent(FinalUtilityBillPayment.this,ListViewBeneficiaryBillPayment.class);
    //FinalUtilityBillPayment.this.startActivity(registerUser);    
    startActivityForResult(registerUser, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

call .dismiss() for closiong it, also use simple Dialog to get the possibility of setting custom layout for it

```
Dialog alert = new Dialog(context);
alert.setContentView(layoutResID);
```