# Android QuickAction Notification View

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, quickaction

I have created topbar like Facebook app now I'm stuck I want to create notification view (Pop Up) like Facebook I am using quickaction but its quite difficult to handle when orientation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achievie but I thing that you should read (if you didn't do it already)

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=347

[Android Quick Actions UI Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059155/android-quick-actions-ui-pattern)

[QuickActions like the Twitter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957860/quickactions-like-the-twitter-app)

Comment: i want ot show similar pop up like facebook does when user click on notification or message button http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=android+facebook+message+notification&hl=en&biw=1152&bih=725&tbm=isch&tbnid=cJt7wyTNfpxQCM:&imgrefurl=http://blixblog.com/%3Fp%3D696&docid=71EEuIMcH5V2YM&imgurl=http://blixblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/screenshot-1324051185926.png&w=320&h=480&ei=c0xCT8iXNcmsrAfTmt3EBw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=509&sig=104881132305940310152&page=1&tbnh=169&tbnw=113&start=0&ndsp=17&ved=0CGYQrQMwCQ&tx=25&ty=38

Comment: Hm... I think that you should create custom QuickAction with custom view inside it. From what I know there is no other way to achieve this.